# Throwing exceptions and try blocks in java

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, throw

I am trying to throw an exception in my support class and trying to catch it in my main class. I am creating a game nim and I am trying to error check my users input. Can you please help me?

Here is my main class file. I am using a try block to catch my exceptions in the other file.

The `NoSuchRowException` is for when a user enters in a number larger than 3 and smaller than one.

The `IllegalSticksException` is when the user enters in more than 3 sticks or less than one stick.

The `NotEnoughSticksException` is when the user enters in more sticks then what is present in the row (creating a negative number).

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        // Player move
        if (e.getSource() == playButton) {

            // Get the row and number of sticks to take
            int row = Integer.parseInt(rowField.getText())-1;
            int sticks = Integer.parseInt(sticksField.getText());

            //Try Block 
            try { nim.play(row, sticks);}
            catch (NoSuchRowException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Row must be between 1-3");
            row = Integer.parseInt(rowField.getText())-1;}

            catch (IllegalSticksException i){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sticks Discarded must be between 1-3");
                sticks = Integer.parseInt(sticksField.getText());}

            catch (NotEnoughSticksException n){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You can not discard more sticks than the amount of sticks avaliable");
                sticks = Integer.parseInt(sticksField.getText());}
            // Play that move
            nim.play(row, sticks);

            // Redisplay the board and enable the AI button
            draw();
            playButton.setEnabled(false);
            AIButton.setEnabled(true);

            // Determine whether the game is over
            if (nim.isOver()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You win!");
                playButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
```

This is my support class. I am trying to throw these exceptions if there is an error in the sticks (S) or rows(R).

```
public void play(int r, int s){

         Sticks[r]=Sticks[r]-s;

        if (r>3||r<1){
            throw new NoSuchRowException();}
        if (r>3||r<1){
            throw new IllegalSticksException();}
        if(s> Sticks[r]){
            throw new NotEnoughSticksException();}

    }
```

Comment: `play(...)` method declaration needs to mention `throws NoSuchRowException, IllegalSticksException, NotEnoughSticksException` unless they are subclasses of RuntimeException. Still, why do you need to call `play(...)` method inside `catch (NotEnoughSticksException n)` block again?

Comment: Have a look at [How to Throw Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html).  Your method needs to define the `Exceptions` it's capable of throwing via the `throws` clause in the method defination

Comment: I wast trying to make it so after the user enters it back in then it will be checked again. my problem is i am getting errors for my Exception names

Comment: I used that that to try code these. I am still really confused on throwing exceptions. Do i need to initialize them under the class method?

Comment: What is the error message that you are getting? Have you defined your custom exceptions anywhere? ie `public class IllegalSticksException extends RuntimeException { ... }`

Comment: @jb. no i have not. Do i create a new file and do that?

Comment: Yes, create a new files for each exception, ie one named NoSuchRowException.java. and add the implementation for each exception. You may also need to import each exception at the top of your other classes. http://java2novice.com/java_exception_handling_examples/create_custom_exception/